# Ошибка с кодировкой при сериализации объекта

Tags: java, кодировка, serializable

Пишу чат на сокетах. Приложение состоит из двух частей, клиента и эхо-сервера. Пересылается объект Message.

Есть проблема: портится кодировка после передачи текста по сокету, то есть нельзя писать русскими буквами. Перепробывал кучу способов кроме стандартного  system.out.print(). Ничего не помогло.

Вот сериализуемый объект.

```
public class Message implements Serializable{

  private String text;

  public Message(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
}
```

Эхо сервер:

```
class Server {
  ServerSocket serverSocket;
  private ObjectInputStream ois ;
  private ObjectOutputStream oos ;
  Message message;   

  public  void start() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
     this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2345);
     Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();         
     ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
     oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

     while(true) {
        message = (Message) ois.readObject();
         System.out.println( message.getText());
        oos.writeObject(message);
     }
  }
}
```

Клиент:

```
class Client extends Thread{
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 Socket socket;
 private ObjectInputStream ois = null;
 private ObjectOutputStream oos = null;   

 public void startClient() throws IOException {
    this.socket = new Socket("localhost" , 2345); 
     oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());                  
     this.start();         
     String string = "";                          
     while ( !string.equals("exit") ) {
         string = scanner.nextLine();
         oos.writeObject(new Message(string));            
    }                  
}

 @Override
 public void run() {
    Message message;                
     try {       
        while (true) {
                message =  (Message) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(message.getText());
        }          
     } catch(Exception e) {}
  }
}
```

Помогите решить проблемму с кодировкой.

Comment: Может надо указать в какой кодировке поступают буквы из стандартного ввода и в какой выводить на вывод?